# Flask Admin but for AIOHTTP

Tags: python, flask, aiohttp

I've been tasked with converting a service from Flask to aiohttp. Originally this service used Flask admin, but we are moving away from Flask. I saw that there is a aiohttp-admin package, but frankly, the documentation is very poor to almost non-existent and I can't wrap my head around the examples. Are there any other options for aiohttp admin pages out there? I've been using Jinja2 templates, but I think my solution is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Which exactly functionality do you lack in aiohttp admin? Please note the demos https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp_admin/tree/master/demos, they might contain fully or partially what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not that they lack functionality I am just unsure how to use it. The demos are confusing to me. They don't tell me if I have to use an ORM or if I can point it to a connection pool. I'm not a web developer so I don't really know Angular or React which are the examples used. Neither template in the examples meets my needs. Jinja2 would be preferable, but I have a feeling it doesn't do it as well as Flask admin does. The documentation for setup doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use jinja2 templates then `aiohttp_admin2` is better for your case. The setup of `aiohttp_admin2` is very simple and good cover into the documentation.

```py
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp_admin2 import setup_admin

app = web.Application()

# setup admin interface
setup_admin(app)

web.run_app(app)
```

It doesn't cover all `flask-admin` features, but you can add your own views or automatically generate CRUD views based on sqlAlchemy's models (or mongodb models) without JavaScript code.

This link to the official repository you can find [here](https://github.com/Arfey/aiohttp_admin2). [Here](https://aiohttp-admin2.readthedocs.io) you can find documentation with demo and examples of code.